# How to change $request_uri in nginx?

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

We get information from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` not from `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

I want to define `$request_uri` to change `/example` to `/module/controller/action`. Please note that I do not want to trigger a redirect.

I tried the code below to do this, but it doesn't work.

```
location /example {
    rewrite /module/controller/action;  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `rewrite ^/example/ /module/controller/action;` work? (directly inside the `server` not in `location`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
set $request_url $request_uri;
if ($request_uri ~ ^/example(.*)$ ) {
    set $request_url /module/controller/action;
}


location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9090;

    #include        fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_url;
    #fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
}
```

Comment: sorry,
I updated question. I dont want to make redirect. I want to define $request_uri to change /example to /module/controller/action

Comment: @muratsac, I updated the anwser, removed `redirect` from the `rewirte` directive.

Comment: Thank you for answer but it doesn't work :(

PHP $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/example' :/

Comment: for example, 
is called brand.html $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value is expected for /brand/index/list

Comment: Do you pass the request to fastcgi, then process the request by php?

Comment: yes I pass the request to fastcgi, then process the request by php

Comment: -1 for going with the complicated pointless way instead of just using `try_files`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, He wants to change the `fastcgi parameter `REQUEST_URI` . Are you sure `try_files` can do this? If yes, can you post an example as the answer? Thank you.

Comment: +many for persistence in finding an answer; and for the above injustice. also, not pointless at all - I control request URI to spoof my internal app routing. quite useful since I have one map.php take all runtime request which can render any portions of the sitemap to ram, disk or network drive as html but also need service calls to access to live php.

Comment: @MichaelHampton try_files won't change $request_uri, which is what needs to be done here

Comment: I dont get it how does that change the request_uri, u just made a variable and set it to the request_uri