# Subdomain as part of REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, request-uri

I have a local site: `http://domain.loc/` and that site have subdomain: `http://sub.domain.loc/`.
How can I configure my `Apache` server || `PHP` to make him return global variable: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'`] with my subdomain name ("sub" in this case)?

Examples:

If I'll open the page `http://domain.loc/` then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be equal to `/` 
If I'll open the page `http://sub.domain.loc/` then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be equal to `/sub/`

Comment: Can I ask you why do you want to do this. `.htaccess` is not ok for you?

Comment: What's the use-case, and why not take `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of only the uri? See [PHP: $_SERVER - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Recently I got a new project with subdomain. Controller, which have to load the main page of the subdomain, included by REQUEST_URI only!!! I don't know how... but it works on DEV and PRODUCTION servers. Can't make it works on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. `REQUEST_URI` is what comes **AFTER** the hostname component of a url:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz
           ^--- HTTP_HOST
                    ^---- REQUEST_URI
```

You can certainly have your subdomain name in the URI component, but that's something YOU have to do, and something Apache+PHP won't. They're not going to rewrite fundamental definitions of URLs just to suit you.

Comment: Looks like it possible... but only with nginx: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869930/how-to-change-request-uri-in-nginx
But I didn't try it. I don't have nginx on my local machine.

Comment: It's not a matter of nginx/apache, it's a matter of php_mod vs php-fpm. The project should be improved instead of hacking your own server to fit a bad implemented project.

Comment: Yes, I think you right. But I'm can't do anything with it, because a huge part of the project which have to be rewritten for that is subrepo and using on other projects.
But still thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` returns the `domain` with the current `subdomain`

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomain = $host[0];
echo $subdomain;
```