# Modifying query url/path without redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, httprequest, puma

I'm trying to figure a way to modify my request URL before it's received by Puma.

Exemple:

User come on the site with a url like **/locale/resource/:id**.
But I want him to be *redirected* to **/locale/'resource/resource-slug** because it's more pretty.

I've already made a first version of this.

```
before_action :redirect_with_pretty_challenge_url, only: %w(index show new edit)

private

def redirect_with_pretty_challenge_url
  param_kind = challenge_show_or_admin_challenges? ? :id : :challenge_id
  return unless params_is_id?(param_kind)

  redirect_to stubbed_request_path_parameters(param_kind)
end

def params_is_id?(param_kind)
  return true if params[param_kind].is_a?(Integer)

  params[param_kind].to_i.to_s == params[param_kind]
end

def stubbed_request_path_parameters(param_kind)
  request.path_parameters[param_kind] = Challenge.find_by_params(params[param_kind])&.slug
  request.path_parameters
end
```

So with this the user is redirected to the 'correct' url, but with a redirection...

I would like to know if there is a way to modify the url directly in the request so that I don't have to redirect_to the user, it will make this action way more 'transparent'.

Is it possible ? Or completely impossible due to the HTTP procotol ?

Comment: You can change the [request URI in nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869930/how-to-change-request-uri-in-nginx) or apache but it will not update the browser address bar - just what Rack/Rails sees as the request uri. IMHO, just learn to live with it instead, your users most likely will never care about the URL.

Comment: Maybe users don't care. But I do. And I want to control what is displayed. Even the url. I guess I'll stick with a good old redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `slugUrl` to a javascript and use `history.replaceState()`:

```
stateObj = history.state     # in the case somebody already uses it
stateObj.url = slugUrl       # will help with turbolinks and like
history.replaceState stateObj, "", url
```

You can, for example, put the `slugUrl` even in the template and put slug building login in the `ApplicationController` helper method.